are there any flaws in this (postgre)sql "setup" (like safety issues)?
I’m looking for someone who is proficient in (postgre)sql and wants to do a quick look at a sql “setup” I’ve made. I will describe what I want to achieve:
I have a postgresql server with a superuser named ‘postgres’ (the default user). I want to create a new database (named ‘db’) and 2 users: ‘db_owner’ and ‘db_user’. db_owner is a user with “unlimited” privileges on the database. db_user is the user I want to use to connect with from a nodejs backend, so this user needs to have limited privileges (eg it cannot drop tables, create functions, and more ‘dangerous’ commands). After creating the database with the postgres user and changing the ownership to db_owner, all the objects in the database (schemas, tables, sequences, functions, …) are created with the db_owner user. All these privileges should also be used in future tables etc (hence the alter default privilegescommands).
I’ve tested this setup and it seems to me that it’s working correctly, but I’m looking for more information if I can (possibly) improve security for this setup.
One remark: I’m adding the extensions pgcrypto and postgis with the db_owner user. For pgcrypto this works, but I have to add postgis with a superuser, so with postgres user. I’m adding both extensions to the extensions schema. I see that the owner of all pgcrypto/postgis-functions is postgres, not db_owner (even if I’ve added pgcrypto with db_owner user). Should it be safe enough to add the superuser privilege to db_owner, because I’m only using this user for database maintenance (creating new tables etc), and there is no software (like my nodejs backend) that uses this user for select/insert/update/delete-queries?
--- connect with role 'postgres' to database 'postgres'

CREATE ROLE db_owner WITH PASSWORD 'password' LOGIN;

CREATE DATABASE db WITH OWNER db_owner;

REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db FROM PUBLIC;

--- connect with role 'db_owner' to database 'db'

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

CREATE SCHEMA extensions;

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA extensions FROM PUBLIC;

--- connect with role 'postgres' to database 'postgres'

CREATE ROLE db_user WITH PASSWORD 'password' LOGIN;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO db_user;

--- connect with role 'db_owner' to database 'db'

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO db_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE db_owner GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMAS to db_user;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO db_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public FOR ROLE db_owner GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO db_user;

GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO db_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public FOR ROLE db_owner GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCES TO db_user;

GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO db_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public FOR ROLE db_owner GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO db_user;

GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA extensions TO db_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA extensions FOR ROLE db_owner GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO db_user;

CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto WITH SCHEMA extensions;

CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA extensions;

CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id bigint DEFAULT nextval('test_seq') NOT NULL,
   value character VARYING DEFAULT NULL NULL
);

ALTER TABLE test_table ADD CONSTRAINT test_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

